# Gradient at minimum makes an acute angle with any direction vector for a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable convex function and $S$ by a closed convex set. If $x \in S$ in the minimizer of $f$ over $S$, I want to prove that, for any $z \in S$,
$$
\langle \nabla f(x), z-x \rangle \geq 0.
$$

Can anyone provide a hint or suggest a method about how to approach this problem?

Comment: Do you conceive a graphical representation of what you have to prove, for example for $d=2$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Yeah, I could do the same for $d=1$ at least.

Comment: @user251257: Now if I take $t \rightarrow 0$ and use the definition of directional derivative, it's done, right?

Comment: yiep ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: All right, but $d=1$ is a very uninteresting case... I advise you for example to take $d=2$ with for example $f(x,y)=x^2+4y^2$ which is convex and take level line $f(x,y)<5$ (interior of an ellipse : convex too). The gradient, say at point $(x=1,y=1)$ is $(2x,8y)=(2,8)$. Do you see it is orthogonal to the curve at this point ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: Yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider some x, y.
From the definition of convexity, we know,
$$
\bigtriangledown f(x)(y - x) > 0 => f(y) > f(x)
$$
And hence we always move in a direction where
$$
\bigtriangledown f(x)(y - x) < 0 
$$
as we want to always go to a **y** that reduces the functional value.
ie. $$ \bigtriangledown f(x)(\Delta x) < 0 $$